# Create A popup InputBox from a cell and right the value to the next one

Tags: excel, vba

Hello this is my first question here and I'm new in VBA programming. I'm looking for a VBA code that would allows me when I select a cell on a range of cells to pop-up an input box to put some values.
For example when I select a cell from column B an input box pops up, requiring a value that goes to next cell in column C. That's because in the column B I have stored a formula (& the cell is locked) and I would not like to be deleted or changed by the user although I need his Input Value to be calculated by the formula, so I choose to store this value in a hidden cell next to it and make the reference into my formula.
How is this possible with VBA? 
Thanks in advance,
Harris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique uses **double click** rather than single click.  Your protection must allow the user to double click cells in column **B**

Enter the following Event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim t As Range, B As Range
    Set t = Target
    Set B = Range("B:B")
    If Intersect(t, B) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    t.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter data value", Type:=1)
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value = Application.InputBox("Insert your value please")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This pops an inputbox up if you select any cell in column B and puts the value to the Cell in C. You have to put the Code directly into the particular Sheet in the VBA Window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I think I will use the double click method, users will find it more practical, thanks any way.